# How do I sort Swift objects by multiple criteria

Tags: sorting, swift

I have a list of Swift objects that I'd like to get sorted by multiple criteria. The objects in the list are of type `DateRange`:

```
class DateRange {
    var from: NSDate?
    var to: NSDate?
}
```

The list contains many of these objects where some `from` or `to` fields are nil. I want to have this list sorted by:

1. First all objects that have dates
2. Then objects that have at least one date (either `from` or `to`)
3. And at the very end objects without any

The dates itself don't matter, just their existence. In Ruby I could do this (if the date is `nil` I set it to a very low date):

```
date_ranges.sort { |a, b|
  [fix_nil(a.from), fix_nil(a.to)] <=> [fix_nil(b.from), fix_nil(b.to)]
}.reverse

def fix_nil(val)
  val.nil? ? Date.new(0) : val
end
```

What's the best way to do this with Swift? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it might be a good idea to add a `dateCount` computed property to your `DateRange` type. This would be a good time for pattern matching:

```
extension DateRange {
    // returns the number of non-nil NSDate members in 'from' and 'to'
    var dateCount: Int {
        switch (from, to) {
        case (nil, nil): return 0
        case (nil, _): return 1
        case (_, nil): return 1
        default: return 2
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can sort your list with a simple closure:

```
var ranges = [DateRange(nil, nil), DateRange(NSDate(), nil), DateRange(nil, NSDate()), DateRange(nil, nil), DateRange(NSDate(), NSDate())]
ranges.sort { $0.dateCount > $1.dateCount }
```

If you wanted, you could even make it `Comparable` with a few more lines:

```
extension DateRange : Comparable { }
func ==(lhs: DateRange, rhs: DateRange) -> Bool {
    return lhs.dateCount == rhs.dateCount
}
func <(lhs: DateRange, rhs: DateRange) -> Bool {
    return lhs.dateCount > rhs.dateCount
}
```

This lets you sort your list properly with an operator argument:

```
ranges.sort(<)
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume that by *list* you mean *array*, so I am basing my answer on that assumption.

You can use the `sort` method of the array struct, which takes a closure having this signature:

```
(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool
```

returning `true` if `lhs` is less than `rhs`, false otherwise.

I came up with this implementation:

```
var x: [DateRange]
// ... initialize the array

x.sort { (lhs: DateRange, rhs: DateRange) -> Bool in
    if lhs.from != nil && lhs.to != nil {
        return true
    }

    if lhs.from == nil && lhs.to == nil {
        return false
    }

    return rhs.from == nil && rhs.to == nil
}
```

- if `lhs` has both properties not nil, then it comes first, regardless of `rhs`
- if `lhs` has both properties nil, then if comes after, regardless of `rhs`
- else `lhs` has one nil, the other not nil, and in that case it comes first only if `rhs` has both properties nil

If you plan to reuse the `sort` in several places, it's better to move the code out of the `sort` method - the best place is probably an overload of the `<` operator:

```
func < (lhs: DateRange, rhs: DateRange) -> Bool {
    if lhs.from != nil && lhs.to != nil {
        return true
    }

    if lhs.from == nil && lhs.to == nil {
        return false
    }

    return rhs.from == nil && rhs.to == nil
}
```

and in that case it can be used as follows:

```
x.sort(<)
```

If you don't like the operator overload, you can of course give that function any other name.

Note that sorting is done *in place*.

Comment: I think your comparison has a bug -- this will return true when comparing two equal `DateRange` instances if they're both `(nil, nil)`.

Comment: That should be covered by the 2nd if: if lhs has both nil, it returns false

Comment: Sorry -- I got that backwards. If both ranges have both dates, this will return true since that first condition is only looking at `lhs`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially the hint with the 'in-place' sorting. I use [ExSwift's](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift/wiki/Array#sortby) `sortBy` function now which works nicely with immutable data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this. To keep things simple, add a scoring function for the date range. In your scenario, you have 3 possibilities:

nil & nil : 0 points

nil & date : 1 point

date & date : 2 points

```
import Foundation

class DateRange {
    var from: NSDate?
    var to: NSDate?

    init(from: NSDate?, to: NSDate?)
    {
        self.from = from
        self.to = to
    }

    func scoreDateRange() -> Int
    {
        var score = 0
        if from != nil
        {
            score++
        }
        if to != nil
        {
            score++
        }
        return score
    }
}

func sortDateRange( d1 : DateRange, d2 : DateRange)-> Bool
{

    return d1.scoreDateRange() > d2.scoreDateRange()
}

var date_ranges = [DateRange]()
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:nil, to:nil))
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:nil, to:nil))
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:NSDate(), to:NSDate()))
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:nil, to:NSDate()))
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:NSDate(), to:nil))
date_ranges.append(DateRange(from:NSDate(), to:NSDate()))

date_ranges.sort(sortDateRange)
```

Comment: Nice idea with the scoring function, thanks for your quick answer!